# ASP NET CORE Identity redirecting to Access Denied when logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am working with [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). My app is configured to require authenticated users globally and Role based authorization is set on Controllers and Action methods as required. On my account controller I have set `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin"]` and on the Logout action of the account controller I used `[Authorize]` expecting that all Authorized users can access the logout action. But with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin"]` set on the controller the user is redirected to Access Denied Route when logout is invoked unless he/she is in the `admin role`  but if the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin"]` is commented out it works for both `admin` and `non admin` users. How can I Allow all authorized users to access logout action? below is my code

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    /*
    Rest of Code
    */

    [HttpPost, Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why authorize the *Logout* function? If someone isn't logged in, it should act as a no-op

Comment: You could just make the `Logout()` action support being anonymous with `[Anonymous]`, then if the user wasn't logged in it would just be a no-op.

Comment: I thought there may be security risk with that......Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Martin Costello says, you could add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute at the Logout method.

As far as I know, the action method's [AllowAnonymous] attribute will not affect other controller's actions. So this method will be security.

Then you could put below codes inside the Logout method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove [Authorize] from logout action